# How to convert multiple date formats from csv by apoc?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
apoc.date.parse('2020-11-04','ms','yyyy-MM-dd')
```

However, my CSV also contains another format:

```
yyyyMMdd
```

For exampl,e '20201104'. Does the parse format can parse two formats, something like:

```
 apoc.date.parse('2020-11-04','ms','yyyy-MM-dd|yyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell, both from the [documentation here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.date/apoc.date.parse/#_signature) and in testing your suggested format, this is not supported.  You'll need to detect which format (e.g. contains "-") the date is in first, and then use a IFTHEN/CASE statement to parse each format separately.  (or clean the data set to standardize date format before you import)

*** NOTE: In testing, I found that the statement below returns a value without throwing an error, however it is a different value (aka almost certainly WRONG).  BEWARE!

```
RETURN apoc.date.parse("2020-11-04", "ms", "yyyyMMdd") AS outputInMs;
```